# Option to delete an answer only visible after a reload

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, vote-to-delete

I used to be able to cast the first downvote on an answer with zero-score and then immediately click the *delete* link under the answer.

Now, I cast the first downvote and then need to refresh the page for the *delete* link to be visible.

Is there a reason why the *delete* link isn't added when casting the first downvote? I liked the faster behavior of the old mechanism.

Comment: I assume you are talking about questions that are already closed as the delete link doesn't appear to non diamonds unless the question is closed.

Comment: The OP is referring to answers: Once an answer has a negative score, 20k users can immediately cast a vote to delete the answer. This is different from questions, for which they can be voted for deletion only once it has been closed. A 20k user can vote to delete a question right after it has been closed; 10k users needs to wait, before to vote to delete a question that is already closed. (If I recall it correctly, 10k users can vote to delete a question 2 days after it has been closed.)

Comment: I found this question just now, @sarnold, because I was planning to make a [meta-tag:feature-request] for the refresh to be unnecessary, now that we have [meta-tag:live-refresh]. Would you be interested in you or me making edits to this, or would you prefer that I post my own question?

Comment: @Josh, sorry I don't have more free time to dedicate to SE; feel free to modify my question to make sense with the new features, or just refer to it from a new question, whichever you think would be most beneficial to getting the overall problem solved. :) Thanks

Comment: @sarnold: Okay, I'll take care of it, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It would be incredibly useful if the **delete answer** was shown automatically when you have the necessary rep and your downvote makes the answer score go below zero. When dealing with the ton of "thanks", "me too" non-answers it's annoying to have to reload the page after downvoting to vote for deletion. And yes, even though i usually re-flag as "not an answer" I often downvote+deletevote, too

Answer (score 3):

I've added a client-side implementation of this feature to the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.16.  This is how it looks like in action:

[image: Animation]

Note that, currently, the implementation has a number of limitations:

- It's currently only enabled for answers, because the [score threshold for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) is pretty simple for answers.  There's no fundamental reason why the code couldn't be made to work for questions too, but it would have to be modified to detect whether the question is closed or not.
- To be safe, the script currently never hides a delete link that it didn't insert, even though the code to do that (if the post is upvoted) already exists.  In particular, this hopefully means it won't inappropriately hide any delete links for ♦ mods.
- The injected delete link does work, but it lacks a few cosmetic details of "real" server-side-generated delete links: the link text won't show the number of existing delete votes on the post, and the confirmation dialog won't show the number of delete votes you have remaining for the day.
- The feature is enabled for users with 20k+ rep on normal SE sites, and for users with 4k+ rep on beta sites.  These *should* correspond to the rep threshold for the [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege, but since the thresholds are [customizable on a per-site basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared), they might be wrong for some sites.  If you know of such a site, please tell me.

Comment: Can you make this work in review queues as well (specifically FP and LA)?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That should be doable, yes. In fact, I suspect that earlier versions of the code may have worked in review, but I may have broken that when I switched to using a different method of monitoring post events. Let me take a closer look...