# Essential Stack Exchange user scripts and the dependencies they utilize

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, javascript, userscript

As part of [our discovery for providing a JavaScript API for user scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372956/718314), we want to know what user scripts you're currently using. This can be used to report user scripts that you use and the global `window.StackExchange` object properties and methods they depend on. This question can also include user scripts that depend on other global objects that we provide like `window.StackOverflow`.

To report a user script, use the following template, and **report only one script per answer**:

```
**User script name:**

**Primary audience:**

**Brief description:**

**Notes:**

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- item 1
- item 2
```

"Primary audience" would most frequently be "all users" but it may also be "close reviewers", "moderators", etc. Feel free to use the "Notes" section to add any details you think are valuable to mention about the user script including frequency of use, importance of access, how much worse your Stack Exchange experience would be without it, etc.

We'd also like to collect all of the individual dependencies used in a table, which will be accepted to keep it pinned as the top answer to this question. If you add an answer, please also add the user script name to the appropriate section of the table.

Knowing what dependencies are commonly used by user scripts will help us understand what dependencies should be available as we [migrate to modules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/718314).

Comment: Dunno about calling them essential, but the main ones from the SOCVR repository are all popular: https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts

Comment: Is it valuable to answer with userscript(s) that _don't_ use Stack Exchange object dependencies (eg. because they use just the API), or is it just useful to catalogue scripts with dependencies that might break?

Comment: @zcoop98 more useful here to just focus on userscripts that have dependencies on `window.StackExchange.*`

Comment: @zcoop98 Yeah, we're focused on the global dependencies we provide on our frontend like `window.StackExchange`. I know there's probably some other global objects (`window.StackOverflow`?) but I'm not sure if they're used in a userscripting context.

Comment: What about the `Svg`/`Stacks` helpers?

Comment: @double-beep Those would be great to list too as they're global dependencies we're providing, though I don't know yet if those will change with our module migration

Comment: @KylePollard `StackOverflow` global object is unlikely to be used widely (that is to say I do not know of any prominent use). That said, `Models` properties look like enums, might be possible to include them in type definitions if published/collaborated with community-maintained?

Comment: I've written two dozen userscripts of various complexity, but no hits when I search for `StackExchange.`. I found that hard to believe, but apparently I never wanted to rely on undocumented features...

Comment: Can someone include Roomba forecaster in the list?

Comment: I created one post per userscript as requested. For the full list with more info, see the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gWpoga0g3O863sTn-wAOJBT3djgz0XZOyMPPbduA7jI/edit?usp=sharing) I created for this purpose, as well as [SOMU repo's readme](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md) for each userscript's features and screenshots.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you add an answer, please also add the userscript name (with a link to your answer) to the appropriate section of the table below.

### `window.StackExchange`

| Property/Method | Scripts (one per line, link to answer) |
| --- | --- |
| `.beginEditEvent.cancel` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.comments.loadAll` | [CheckForExistingCorA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372976) |
| `.comments.uiForPost` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.helpers.addSpinner` | ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372968) |
| `.helpers.bindMovablePopups` | [AutoReviewComments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372966) [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.helpers.closePopus` | [Flag Dialog Smokey Controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372982) |
| `.helpers.removeSpinner` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.helpers.removeSpinner` | ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372968) |
| `.helpers.showConfirmModal` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.helpers.showErrorMessage` | [Flag Dialog Smokey Controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372982) |
| `.helpers.showErrorPopup` | ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372968) |
| `.helpers.showModal` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.helpers.showSuccessMessage` | [Flag Dialog Smokey Controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372982) |
| `.helpers.showToast` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.helpers.using` | [Inline editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372971) |
| `.ifUsing` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.inlineEditing.init` | [Inline editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372971) |
| `.initialized` | [CheckForExistingCorA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372976) |
| `.notify.close` | [CheckForExistingCorA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372976) [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.notify.show` | [CheckForExistingCorA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372976) [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.options.site.isMetaSite` | [UserInfoSidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375221/786798) |
| `.options.site.name` | [AutoReviewComments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372966) |
| `.options.user.fkey` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.options.user.isModerator` | [Mod Flagger Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372967) [Flag Dialog Smokey Controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372982) [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |
| `.options.user.userId` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) [Mod Flagger Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372967) [AutoReviewComments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372966) |
| `.question.bindSuggestedEditPopupLinks` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.question.getQuestionId` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |
| `.question.init` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.question.initFull` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |
| `.ready` | [AutoReviewComments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372966) [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) [Format Stack Jobs CV for printing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374740/153187) [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |
| `.realtime.updateRelativeDates` | [UserReviewBanHelper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375223/786798) |
| `.using` | [SE CV Request Generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372984/288337) |

### `window.Stacks`

| Property/Method | Scripts (one per line, link to answer) |
| --- | --- |
| `.application.register` | [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |
| `.attachPopover` | [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |
| `.setTooltipText` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.setTooltipHtml` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.showModal` | [Advanced Flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372964) |
| `.StacksController` | [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |

### `window.Svg`

It would be nice to keep all the properties of that object or provide an API to create Stacks SVGs by name.

| Property/Method | Scripts (one per line, link to answer) |
| --- | --- |
| `.Person` | [Bookmark Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375732/140890) |

Comment: @Machavity Edit - feel free to replace the sample with your items, it's just there as a placeholder. Hopefully we won't end up with a ton of edits all at the same time... :/ Also, if someone's using a different object, create a new table with that object as the header.

Comment: Is it acceptable to add a property/method without an accompanying userscript? I would like to avoid self-promotion and do not currently have the bandwidth to check through other more prominent scripts, but think that a certain method is very important.

Answer (score 18):

**Userscript name**: [Advanced Flagging](https://github.com/SOBotics/AdvancedFlagging)

**Primary audience**: power users, content curators, people who like flagging posts a lot in general.

**Brief description**: adds an "Advanced Flagging" menu to posts to easily raise flags in two clicks and optionally leave helpful comments on the post based on the flag reasons. Additionally, it integrates with different existing bots/services ([Smokey](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/Build-Infrastructure#smokey), [Natty](https://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natty-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all), [Guttenberg](https://stackapps.com/questions/7197/guttenberg-a-bot-searching-for-plagiarism-on-stack-overflow), [GenericBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/7337/generic-bot-a-moderation-chatbot)) to detect reported posts and automatically send reports/feedback when flagging through its interface.

**Notes**: I am not a developer of this script, just an user, but this is easily the most useful script I use. It makes flagging and giving quick feedback through templated comments an effortless task.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized**:

- `StackExchange.options.user.userId` (self explanatory).
- `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` to authenticate requests.
- `StackExchange.comments.uiForPost` to display comments after automatically adding them (through POST).
- `StackExchange.helpers.showToast` for simple status notifications.
- `StackExchange.helpers.showModal` for configuration modals.
- `StackExchange.helpers.showConfirmModal` for [MetaSmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/) auth.

---

- `Stacks.setTooltipText` - to add a Stacks tooltip with text to an element
- `Stacks.setTooltipHtml` - to add a Stacks tooltip with HTML to an element
- `Stacks.showModal` - to make a Stacks mdoal visible given its HTML element

Answer (score 14):

**Userscript name:** ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082)

**Primary audience:** <1k users

**Brief description:** Currently, it's not possible for users without the ["established user"](/help/privileges/established-user) privilege to view vote counts. This userscript makes them available for everyone.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- `StackExchange.helpers.addSpinner()` - should probably be replaced with Stacks' helpers (`.addStacksSpinner()`, though)
- `StackExchange.helpers.removeSpinner()`
- `StackExchange.helpers.showErrorPopup()`

Answer (score 13):

**Userscript name:** [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/blob/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js) ([Machavity fork](https://github.com/machavity/SE-AutoReviewComments/blob/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js), but there's bound to be others)

**Primary audience:** [SOCVR canned comment list users](https://comments.socvr.org/)

**Brief description:** I still use the super-old [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). It's... been abandoned so I made my own fork (I know I'm not the only fork out there either) to keep it working for our use.

**Notes:** Up until now, it's just been CSS changes breaking things.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- `StackExchange.ready`
- `StackExchange.options.site.name`
- `StackExchange.options`
- `StackExchange.options.user`
- `StackExchange.options.user.userId`
- `StackExchange.helpers.bindMovablePopups()`

Answer (score 9):

**User script name**: [Stack Exchange CV Request Generator](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#so-close-vote-request-generator)

**Primary audience**: room members (owners, regulars or visitors) of [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (mainly), [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta),  [SE Code Review Close Questions room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85306/se-code-review-close-questions-room), [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured), [The Stack Exchange Network](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11254/the-stack-exchange-network). Used a lot by SOCRV regulars.

**Brief description**: adds a "cv-pls" or "del-pls" menu to questions (and a couple of checkboxes in the close reason popup) which can be used to automatically send [cv-pls or del-pls requests](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) in different sites' chatrooms (e.g. most notably [SOCVR on Stack Overflow](https://socvr.org/tour)).

**Notes**: not a dev, just a user of the script. I find this pretty useful even if I do not create a lot of requests myself. When I do though, this makes it an order of magnitude easier and faster than copy-pasting the question title, tags and link into the chatroom manually. Feel free to edit the list below if I missed something!

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized**:

- `StackExchange.{ready,ifUsing}` to detect if/when different `StackExchange` functionalities are available to use.
- `StackExchange.notify.{show,close}` as a better alternative to `window.alert()`.
- The following methods are not explicitly used, but they are replaced with a wrapper that emits events when called, so the script has a chance to add the "cv-pls" menu button at the right time:

  - `StackExchange.question.init`
  - `StackExchange.question.initFull`
  - `StackExchange.question.getQuestionId`
  - `StackExchange.question.bindSuggestedEditPopupLinks`
  - `StackExchange.beginEditEvent.cancel`
  - `StackExchange.using`
  - `StackExchange.helpers.removeSpinner`
- `StackExchange.helpers.bindMovablePopups`: this is also wrapped in the same way and detects when the close reason selection popup is opened after clicking "Close" on a question.

Answer (score 8):

**User script name:** [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) (SOUP)

**Primary audience:** General audience of all Stack Exchange sites, who frequently run into minor client-side issues in SE's current code

**Brief description:** To quote the [GitHub repository description](https://github.com/vyznev/soup):

> The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP) is a project to collect various minor client-side bug fixes, work-arounds and usability improvements for Stack Overflow and other Q&A sites on the Stack Exchange Network into a single user script.
>
> The intent of SOUP is not to make any substantial or controversial changes to the Stack Exchange user interface, but to fix minor problems and omissions that the SE developers have overlooked or haven't got around to fixing yet. By combining these minor patches into a single user script, they become easier to install and maintain.

**Notes:** I run into quite a few of the client-side issues that this script addresses. As examples, I frequently click the top of the "Linked" bar on a question to access the full list of linked questions, and prefer to be able to see the "Close" button on a question in a different color if I've cast a close vote on it; both of these among others I frequently hit are implemented in this script.

The way the script's code is structured makes it easy for me to add additional fixes to my own copy of the script to work around other issues, which would be hard to do in their own, separate user scripts.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

Note that some of the fixes the script makes are no longer necessary as they were actually fixed by SE. Some other fixes also no longer work due to later SE changes, but that doesn't mean the code for them is no longer valuable: generally, it's just a class name change or similar.

- `StackExchange.helpers.submitFormOnEnterPress` - used to work around [this (possibly fixed) Firefox bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66646/confirming-context-menu-entries-via-enter-when-entering-comments-triggers-commen) where pressing Enter in a context menu when composing a comment (e.g. client-side spell checkers) would unexpectedly submit the comment; team declined to fix as it only affected Firefox
- `StackExchange.options.user` - implements [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115702) for 20k+ users to have the delete button shown on answers immediately after casting a downvote rather than after a page refresh
- `StackExchange.helpers.disableSubmitButton` - used to disable the comment submission button as part of a fix for [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310158) that text direction marker characters in comments cause other elements on the page to change
- `StackExchange.options.user.userId` - used to find the current user's ID so that the "flags remaining" text in the flag dialog can link to the user's flag history

...plus some others, which I omitted due to the fixes being obsolete due to them being since implemented in SE code. I'd strongly recommend going through each of its fixes and implementing it in SE code so that it isn't necessary to maintain workarounds so this script continues to work.

Answer (score 5):

**Userscript name:** [Inline editor regardless of reputation](https://stackapps.com/questions/6216) (also part of [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091))

**Primary audience:** <2k users

**Brief description:** In order for inline editing, users need to have the ["edit questions and answers"](/help/privileges/edit) privilege. This userscript allows inline post editing even if the user is <2k rep.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- `StackExchange.using` - check if `.inlineEditing` exists
- `StackExchange.inlineEditing.init()` - run inline editing JS

Answer (score 5):

**Userscript name:**  *CheckForExistingCorA* [Show a warning message when you follow a link to a deleted answer or comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/7376)

**Primary audience:** Users that follow Smokey reported posts

**Brief description:** It can be confusing when a spam post / rude comment is already deleted but you can't really tell as there is no clear feedback. This script fixes that lack of feedback.

**Notes:** See also the original answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251236

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- `StackExchange.initialized`
- `StackExchange.notify`
- `StackExchange.comments`

Answer (score 4):

**Userscript name**: [Mod Flagger Stats](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ModFlaggerStats.user.js)

**Primary audience**: moderators and people obsessed with their helpful vs declined post flags ratio (like me).

**Brief description**: calculate and show user flagging statistics on hover in the mod flag queue and on user profiles. If not a mod, only shows a badge near your name in your user profile.

**Notes**: part of [Samuel Liew's SO-mod-userscripts collection](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts). I'm not the original dev, just a user and contributor.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized**:

- `StackExchange.options.user.userId` (self explanatory).
- `StackExchange.options.user.isModerator` for mod status detection.

Answer (score 4):

**User script name:** [Flag Dialog Smokey Controls](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/userscripts/raw/master/fdsc/fdsc.user.js)

**Primary audience:** Spam fighters (Charcoal)

**Brief description:** Enhances the flag dialog to automatically provide feedback to Metasmoke (basically, a database with information about possible spam posts)

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- `StackExchange.helpers.closePopups`
- `StackExchange.helpers.showErrorMessage`
- `StackExchange.helpers.showSuccessMessage`
- `StackExchange.options.user.isModerator`

Answer (score 4):

**Userscript name:**
AdditionalPostModActions

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Adds a menu with mod-only quick actions in post sidebar

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl
StackExchange.options.site.childUrl
StackExchange.helpers.showErrorMessage()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Userscript name:** [Generic Review Tool](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/blob/main/generic-review-tool.user.js) (GRT)

**Primary audience:** Reviewers

**Brief description:** Automatically detects new review tasks and opens them in a new tab (a much lighter weight and actively maintained replacement for the older Review Stalker and Review Stalker Reloaded)

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

GRT does not currently use any `window.StackExchange` methods; HTML/CSS changes are the main thing which occasionally breaks GRT/RSR (and some other scripts I've made which aren't worth posting here).

I also uh...didn't actually realize you could get the site ID using `window.StackExchange`, and that would make the code a lot cleaner for one of my older scripts (not going to post it here, since it was horribly hacked together and broke ages ago due to HTML/CSS stuff).

Answer (score 3):

**Userscript name:**
CommentFlagsHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Always expand comments (with deleted) and highlight expanded flagged comments, Highlight common chatty and rude keywords

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
```

Answer (score 3):

**Userscript name:**
DuplicateAnswersFlagsHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Add action button to delete AND insert duplicate comment at the same time

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.user.userId
```

Answer (score 3):

**Userscript name:**
SearchbarNavImprovements

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Searchbar & Nav Improvements. Advanced search helper when search box is focused. Bookmark any search for reuse (stored locally, per-site).

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.site.routePrefix
StackExchange.options.site.isChildMeta
StackExchange.options.site.name
StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl
StackExchange.options.site.childUrl
```

Answer (score 3):

**Userscript name:**
UserReviewBanHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Display users' prior review bans in review, Insert review ban button in user review ban history page, Load ban form for user if user ID passed via hash

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.site.name
StackExchange.realtime.updateRelativeDates()
StackExchange.using("stacksEditor", ...)
StackExchange.stacksEditor.createAsync()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Userscript name:**
CreatePrivateModChatroom

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
One-click button to create private/mod chat room with user and grant write access

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 2):

**Userscript name:**
AdditionalInlinePostModMenu

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Adds mod-only quick actions in existing post menu

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl
StackExchange.options.site.childUrl
StackExchange.helpers.showErrorMessage()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Userscript name:**
DisplayInlineCommentFlagHistory

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Grabs post timelines and display comment flag counts beside post comments, on comment hover displays flags

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 2):

**Userscript name:**
ModeratorHistoryImprovements

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Better UI for mod action history page. Auto-refresh every minute.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.realtime.updateRelativeDates()
```

Answer (score 2):

**User script name:**
Bookmark users

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/mjpieters/SO-userscripts/tree/main/scripts/bookmark-users

**Primary audience:** Moderators

**Brief description:** Shows who has bookmarked a question, loading the list from SEDE and augmenting it with API data for each user.

**Notes:**

I looked for but did not find a method for formatting user reputation. I settled on using 2 `Intl.NumberFormat()` setups, one for unabbreviated scores (below 10k) and one for everything above. See the [`users.ts` file](https://github.com/mjpieters/SO-userscripts/blob/1ab93118b63930a94a4e60769bdbc9de84dd5b84/scripts/bookmark-users/src/users.ts). I'd love to see the API provide this.

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

- `StackExchange.options.user.isModerator` - deleted user accounts are not linked when the user is not a moderator.
- `StackExchange.question.getQuestionId` - the current post ID to load bookmarks for
- `StackExchange.ready` - only register the UI components when StackExchange is ready
- `Stacks.application.register` - to register the controller
- `Stacks.attachPopover` - the controller attaches a new popover
- `Stacks.StacksController` - the extension is implemented as a Stimulus controller
- `Svg.Person` - the icon used as the button to open the dialog box with users

The script makes heavy use of the Stacks CSS and JS frameworks, so I'm guessing that it is already quite far along the same direction that the StackExchange API would be heading.

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:** Format Stack Jobs CV for printing

**Primary audience:** Just me.  It's unpublished.  I expect that others could use something similar if they wanted to customize the traditional view of their Dev Story for printing and/or PDF export.

**Brief description:** Maintains the non-printable view when printing.  Modifies that view to optimize page breaks, add a LinkedIn URL in the header, rearrange some sections, and miscellaneous other layout tweaks.

**List of objects/properties/methods:**

`StackExchange.ready(...)`, which is easily replaced.  Also, lots of CSS properties.  I generally need to update the script anytime I want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
DeclinedFlagsNotifier

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Show topbar indicator for recently declined flags

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
DeletedUsersHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Additional capability and improvements to display/handle deleted users

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
FetchQuestionStats

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Display number of comments on each post in question lists. For mod queues, additional info (recent revision history) is also retrieved.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
FetchVoteCountsAgain

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Fetch vote counts for posts and enables you to click to fetch them again, even if you do not have sufficient rep. Also enables fetch vote counts on posts in mod flag queue as well as question/search lists!!!

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.rep
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.helpers.addStacksSpinner()
StackExchange.helpers.removeSpinner()
StackExchange.ready()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
ModBatchCommentDeleter

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Batch delete comments using comment permalinks from SEDE

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.site.name
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
ModFlaggerStats

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Post hover in mod flag queue, get and display flaggers stats. Badge links to user's flag history. Non-mods only can view their own flag badge on profile.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
ModMessageHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Adds menu to quickly send mod messages to users

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl
StackExchange.options.site.name
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
ModPopupDialogImprovements

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Some simple improvements for posts' Mod popup dialog

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
ModUserQuicklinksEverywhere

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Adds quicklinks to user infobox in posts

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.site.isChildMeta
StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
NotAnAnswerFlagQueueHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Inserts several sort options for the NAA / VLQ / Review LQ Disputed queues

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.moderator.renderTimeTicks
StackExchange.options.user.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PersonalModMessageHistory

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Displays your sent mod messages

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PossibleVandalismCommentDeletionsHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Display deleted comments and user who deleted the comments

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PossibleVandalismDeletionsHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Display post score and number of undeleted answers, Recommend action based on post info

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PossibleVandalismEditsHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Display revision count and post age

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PostBanDeletedPosts

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
When user posts on SO Meta regarding a post ban, fetch and display deleted posts (must be mod) and provide easy way to copy the results into a comment

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.site.name
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PostHeadersQuestionToc

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Sticky post headers while you view each post (helps for long posts). Question ToC of Answers in sidebar.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.site.routePrefix
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
PostTimelineFilters

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Inserts several filter options for post timelines

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
RejectedSuggestedEdits

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
New page to review rejected suggested edits

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.site.name
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.helpers.addSpinner()
StackExchange.helpers.removeSpinner()
StackExchange.realtime.updateRelativeDates()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
ReviewQueueHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Keyboard shortcuts, skips accepted questions and audits (to save review quota)

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.vote.init(pid)
StackExchange.helpers.showToast()
StackExchange.options.user.rep
StackExchange.options.user.canSeeDeletedPosts
StackExchange.inlineEditing.init()
StackExchange.question.initShareLinks()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
StackPrintStyles

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Print preprocessor and print styles for Stack Exchange Q&A, blog, and chat. Includes a handy load all comments button at bottom right.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
SuspiciousVotingHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Assists in building suspicious votes CM messages. Highlight same users across IPxref table.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
TooManyCommentsFlagQueueHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Inserts quicklinks to "Move comments to chat + delete" and "Delete all comments"

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
StackExchange.moderator.renderTimeTicks
StackExchange.options.user.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
UserActivityNotifications

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Display notifications on user profile when new activity is detected since page load

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
UserInfoSidebar

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Adds user moderation links sidebar with quicklinks & user details (from Mod Dashboard) to user-specific pages

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.site.isMetaSite
StackExchange.options.site.parentUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
UserlinkTooltips

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Display reputation in tooltip upon user link mouseover

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
UserSocialMediaProfileLinks

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
When PII is loaded, linkify social media profile strings

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
FindUsersAdditionalInfo

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Loads more user details on the find users page

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 1):

**Userscript name:**
MigrationHelper

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Dropdown list of migration targets displaying site icon/logo/header images and links to the selected site's on-topic page and mod list. Displays additional information for custom flagger for selected network site.

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 0):

**Userscript name:**
ElectionSupporterFlairs

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Everyone

**Brief description:**
Flair users who voted in the elections when you were elected, or if non-mod, for the latest election

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.userId
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
```

Answer (score 0):

**Userscript name:**
CommentUndeleter

**Userscript repo:**
https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

**Primary audience:**
Moderators

**Brief description:**
Allows moderators to undelete user-deleted comments

*For full description and screenshots, please see [README.md](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md)*

**List of objects/properties/methods utilized:**

```
StackExchange.options.user.isModerator
StackExchange.options.user.fkey
```