# Logout from all Stack Exchange sites without triggering the title bar notifications (and also without refreshing them)?

Tags: discussion, notifications, logout

This is about a feature that lets me log out without having to open a normal SE site. All of the tabs shall stay open, I want to work on them further when I log in again. This is a logout page where you do not see the title bar notifications or anything else, just the logout button. One could then discuss whether you should be able to log out only globally from all of your accounts or whether you should also be able to choose which SE sites you want to log out.

What about a global Stack Exchange logout page that does not show anything of the title bar notifications and that does not count the visit - as if you had not been there at all? How could that be planned so that it would become a good feature request, if at all?

*-- This question has been shrunk down to the core, some comments hint at the older version of the question. --*

As to the accepted answer: the idea was that the "logout visit" would not be counted - as if I was not there - and therefore the changes would also not update. If I clicked by chance on an open tab some days later, and I am still logged out, I would only see changes that I already know, from my latest refresh when being logged in. This is not in the accepted answer (which is a fast and good workaround only), but it was the idea of the feature.

Comment: why not just use incognito mode?

Comment: If this is a scholary or professional environment you guys should really have some global log-in system so that you can work with your own account on any machine

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There are many reasons. One is that you can have dozens of SE tabs open but do not want to touch them at that time and still want to read through many other non-SE tabs that you saved yourself up for later. You need to care for where you click and which neighboured tab you close then, for example. But you can find 10 bullet points more.

Comment: @Luuklag It is for me, and for me.

Comment: I think overall this feature, while having merit for you and maybe a few others, is so specific for a narrow use-case where I doubt if such a feature when implemented at SE ends of the wire fully covers your needs. The feature seem to have a security/privacy aspect as well, so when done wrong can have huge impact. Wouldn't you feel more confident if you have a local to your machine tailored solution with browsers / OS settings etc that would work for all internet sites where you have an account instead of only SE?

Comment: @rene Not sure if I understand. I thought I could stick to the Gollum humour, yet I better explain it. I am the only user, just with changing sides (work/weekend, and another non-tech SE account sometimes). There is no security problem in my feature discussion here. I just want a way to log off on a day when I do not want to "open SE only to log it off". If this feature is not there, I need to log off in advance, which I need to plan, and I do not want to plan anything. This is just one point of many more you could make for such a feature.

Comment: This seems to be exactly the type of use-case for which browser "profiles" (Firefox) / "users" (Chrome) exist. Just set up an additional "User" or "Profile", depending on your browser of choice, or use a completely separate browser (e.g. if you use Chrome normally, then just use Firefox for the other "user"). This really isn't a feature that should be implemented on a site-by-site basis (i.e. it shouldn't be implemented by Stack Exchange) This is something that *already exists* at both the browser level and OS login level.

Comment: You can, at any time when logged in, goto [/logout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) and tick the 'logout on all devices' and that will invalidate all sessions

Comment: @rene I know that I can log out. That is the reason for this discussion: I do not want to see the new changes when I log out, and I do not want it to be counted as a visit when I only want to log out (without seeing the new changes).

Comment: @Makyen I use two browsers and many windows anyway but I mix the SE tabs and other tabs during the week. When I close a tab I might land at a neighboured SE tab, which would then show me the title bar changes when I am still logged in and which would count the visit. I want to have the freedom to log out without any trace of having been there at that time and without the updates of the title bar. This gives me the freedom to decide during the day about skipping SE for that day. Just as an example, to avoid any triggers that could keep me at the computer longer than needed on a workfree day.

Comment: So, if you would have an AutoIT script or browser plugin that responds to a hotkey and then closes any open tabs that have an address that belongs to the SE network, would work for you? It is still unclear what you expect the developers from SE to build for you. Should they write software to close the tabs for you?

Comment: @rene I think of a feature that lets me log out without having to open a normal SE site. All of the tabs shall stay open, I want to work on them further when I log in again. This is a logout page where you do not see the title bar notifications or anything else, just the logout button. One could then discuss whether you should be able to log out only globally from all of your accounts or whether you should also be able to choose which SE sites you want to log out.

Comment: Create a user script for '*/users/logout' and run `$('.js-top-bar').hide(); $('body').css('padding-top',0);`. Then you can visit in a new tab [se site]/users/logout and you'll only have a logout button, no top-bar, not even the padding, no distractions and you can click logout.

Comment: @rene I see there are [many user scripts around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372957/essential-stack-exchange-user-scripts-and-the-dependencies-they-utilize)! Never heard of. Before I search further, is there any guide about how to create it at all? I am new to this. I only see the ready-made ones. Looks good. Small thing only: for the statistics, a mere logout should better not be counted as a visit. That is likely something that only Stack Exchange developers could write. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Found a good start in a comment there, [Stack Overflow Moderation Userscripts](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md), it needs to be written in a js file like [this](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/StackExchangeWiderMode.user.js).

Comment: There is a whole site with userscripts targetted at SE sites: https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script  (not sure if a disclaimer/affiliation is warranted upfront but I'm a moderator on that site. My recommendation might be biased)

Comment: *"When I close a tab I might land at a neighboured SE tab, which would then show me the title bar changes when I am still logged in and which would count the visit...Just as an example, to avoid any triggers that could keep me at the computer longer than needed on a workfree day."* I don't understand how logging out solves the problem of title bar changes. You can still land on a SE tab when closing another one and it would still indicate there are changes, if they exist.

Comment: @BSMP You would not see any new changes, I give only a few of many examples. Most of the time, I check the changes before leaving the computer. It is mainly about the changes that come in the meantime.

Comment: @BSMP you mean that one can see changes even after having logged out. I agree, though you cannot plan with it, sometimes, you see changes only if you refresh the site. You still would get the freedom to log out without the need to see the title bar changes. The idea was that the visit would not be counted - as if I was not there - and therefore the changes would also not update. This is not in the accepted answer (which is just a fast and good workaround), but it was the idea of the feature.

Comment: go into your browser and delete stackexchange session cookies?

Comment: @Esther not sure whether that would help, you mean together with the accepted answer then? Or could your comment be a full answer in that with deleted session cookies, even Stack Exchange would not know whether I was there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt you're best served with a solution implemented by Stack Exchange. Your problem seems to be better suited for a personal / local productivity tweak. For browser based options, *[userscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript)* can be a useful and flexible solution.

For example, this user script will hide the top bar on the logout page:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         cleanlogout
// @namespace    https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  No distractions logout
// @author       rene
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/users/logout
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match        https://superuser.com/users/logout
// @match        https://serverfault.com/users/logout
// @match        https://askubuntu.com/users/logout
// @match        https://mathoverflow.net/users/logout
// @match        https://stackapps.com/users/logout
// @run-at       document-start
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackexchange.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

/*global $ */

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('.js-top-bar').hide();
    $('body').css('padding-top',0);
})();
```

Do install a userscript manager—I tested with [Tampermonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey) in Chrome and then added the above script—and you're good to go. With the userscript running, your logout page will now look like:

[image]

That might still count as a visit, but at least it got rid of the distractions on that page, so you can focus on the task: Logout!

Comment: I was not aware of that logout website up to now, thought you linked to the top right symbol logout in your comment. With that, there is also the stone age way: hide the top right of the screen with the hand or a folded paper or the like so that you do not see the title bar. Then log out. The counts on that meta website are statistically less distorting since I seldomly go there anyway. Well. Stone age and childhood is over :), your answer is better.

Comment: It is also good to know that https://stackexchange.com/ does not count any login in any of the account pages, it is just the overview of all accounts.

Answer (score 0):

From the helpful comments and the accepted answer it turns out that **opening https://stackexchange.com/ does not count any login** in any of the account pages, it is just the overview of all accounts, and it offers you the chance to log out without entering any other Stack Exchange - and without seeing any reputation changes in the notification bar.

In other words: entering https://stackexchange.com/ does not lead to "forgotten" reputation changes on another Stack Exchange site. If you open another Stack Exchange afterwards, you will still see the green reputation changes.
This is what this question was about: I can log in on https://stackexchange.com/, then log out from any sites of my choice without seeing any changes, and then click on opened tags without seeing any new changes while I am logged out.

Thus, what this question asks for has already been done.

##### 20230330

A box pops up when you view an opened tab after having logged out with that "logout on stackexchange trick" (=logging out from another https://stackexchange.com/ tab) and then click on the badge symbol to check the +10:

[image]

The +10 reputation change was from an earlier change that I had already seen, and later, I have not seen this against, perhaps it is a lag or bug. At least, it is not a *new* reputation change, and that is the main thing.

Seems as if they have worked on it in the meantime, this change would also be a sort of answer to this already deleted question: [After logout, but leaving the browser tab open, the top bar still shows inbox and achievements changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416172/after-logout-but-leaving-the-browser-tab-open-the-top-bar-still-shows-inbox-an).

If you still see *new* reputation changes in other still opened tabs even after having logged out with the "logout on stackexchange trick" (=logging out from another https://stackexchange.com/ tab), try re-opening your browser after the logout.